# init.rc not starting my service on first boot after flash

Tags: android, permissions, boot, init

I have a service that I am trying to start with the init.rc file in Android.  It looks like this:

```
service myapp /data/local/myapp --daemon  
 class core  
 user root  
 group root  
 oneshot
```

The problem is that 'myapp' starts fine after a reboot but not on the first boot after flashing the device images.

From the logs, I notice that on the first boot logs I receive a log from my app under /dev/log/system (that the kernel code that i edited triggered, checking to verify that my app is there)

however I don't receive a log showing that I am trying to actually run it (as the init.rc file should do)

after reboot I receive both logs (--verify and executing) under /dev/log/main ...

Comment: you have gingerbread or ics ?

Comment: I know this is 3 years old now, but did you ever get to the bottom of this?